# Beginner - PowerShell function to Add user to particular group

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to Powershell. I'm trying to create some basic functions for the task I do at work.
We have 5-6 AD groups that we have to add users on daily basis. I thought I automate that process as a way to learn PS.

Please review my script and comment on areas I need to improve on. My main question is this, Is this the correct way to script for let's say, one user is already part of the group I select and one is not part of the group. I know this script works as it uses a for each statement to loop.

Let me know your thoughts.

```
Function Add-JbSecurefoldergroup {
 [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]

param (
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string[]]$identity, 
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]$Access
)

# Creating a hash table of all security group
$ADSecureGroups = @{ 
    'TD' = 'TD_Security'
    'Intact' = 'Intact_Security'
    'Eco' = 'Eco_Security'
    'VCE' = 'VCE_Security'
    }

# Creating a loop in case I have to add more than one user to the same group

foreach ($AdUserID in $identity) {


# Getting the list of group users is part of
$Adgroupmemberof = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $AdUserID


# Check to see if user not part of the selected group and add them on.
if ( -not ($Adgroupmemberof -match $ADSecureGroups[$Access])) {
        Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $AdUserID -MemberOf $ADSecureGroups[$Access] 

        Write-Host "$AdUserID was added to" $ADSecureGroups[$Access]

    }
    else {
       
       
        Write-Warning "One or more users is already part of the selected group `n" 

        Write-Output " $AdUserID is part of these groups `n"
        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $AdUserID | Select-Object Name | FT
        Write-Output '-----------------------------'
}}}
```

Comment: Your question is more appropriate at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell).

Comment: For one thing, you don't have to call `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $AdUserID` again in the `else` block, because you already have that information in variable `$Adgroupmemberof`